# Unable to link account in Device Access Console

Tags: nest-device-access

I created project in device access console and established my OAuth.  When I add my project and id into the script I receive the following error in the browser:

Can't link to NewHA

I am new to this - so any advise is appreciated

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. Seems like we're both dealing with Home Assistant.

Answer (score -1):

first when you make the first request:

````
redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&
access_type=offline&
prompt=consent&
client_id=oauth2-client-id&
response_type=code&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service```

the `project_id` references to the sandbox project_id.

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize?authuser=4#link_your_account
"Open the following link in a web browser, **replacing project-id with your Device Access Project ID** and oauth2-client-id with the OAuth2 Client ID from your GCP Credentials"


**another issue you may have** can happen from the account you used to open the device-access-Project. **it must be a private and not G suit account** (ending with @gmail.com and not @comapyName.com).
this is because the nest doesn't let you create a G Suit account (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074857/pcm-no-access-to-partner) 

and you can't invite a private nest user to your google home while using the G suit user (as this isn't possible)- 
https://support.google.com/googlenest/thread/426784?hl=en&msgid=560455
so even if you created the 'sandbox' with the G-suitaccount you can't use it to invite a private user (and will have to re open the account and pay again 5$)
````