# PCM: No access to partner

Tags: nest-device-access

Trouble with the Partner Connections Manager (PCM) while following the Quick Start Guide. Steps taken:

1. Enabled the Smart Device Management API
2. Configured the OAuth-permission screen
3. Added the scope for "Smart Device Management API ../auth/sdm.service "
4. Created an OAuth token for a new Web Server
5. Created a new project in the Google Device Access console and used the OAuth 2.0 Client ID
6. Fired the PCM url as instructed in https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize
7. Select my personal gmail where all Nest is now connected
8. get below error

> **No access to partner**
> Information could not be retrieved. Please contact *Device Access console project name* to verify that your account has been properly set up. You may need to add the developer email address as a home member in the Google Home app settings.

No idea what the error means. I'm confused as my step #3, adding scope for SDM API, isn't in the Quick Start Guide and requires verification. But I read you should get an 'unverified warning' while connecting with PCM.

Any clues?

[edit]

Shortly after posting I figured it out. I created the new project on the Google Device Access console with my GSuite account. This is useless because you can't add GSuite accounts to Nest. Therefor you ALWAYS get this error. I want my $5 back :)

Answer (score 1):

They have fixed it now. Solution is to add the developer account in Home App (my developer account with Google SDM and account owning the NEST was different). For production, one would have to request to migrate out of sandbox account.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lzTF.png)