# Device Access Authentication "No partner connections found"

Tags: nest-device-access

I'm currently trying to get an Android app set up to access a nest camera through the new Device Access API, but running into a rather strange snag when following the instructions in the quick start guide. I use the URL under step 1 of "Link your account" in "Authorize an Account" to get an authorization code. I can log in and set the Google Nest Permissions (Step 3), but I can't seem to get to Step 4. where you "Choose an account to continue to Project Name". Instead, I get a screen that simply says "No partner connections found".

I want to chalk this up as being an Android issue, but just throwing the URL https://nestservices.google.com/partnerconnections/project-id/auth with the default information (project ID and client ID as specified in Step 1.) into a browser, will get me only to Step 3 as well. After which, I get an Authorization Error with Error Code 400: redirect_uri_mismatch (the redirect_uri is the default https://www.google.com). So, I think I may be missing something.

As extra information, the nest camera is activated through the same gmail account as the one used to create the Device Access Console Project. I've tried creating a new oauth2 credential with the same gmail account with no change in behavior. I'm wondering if I'm missing anything from the documentation.

Comment: Isn't this the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074857/pcm-no-access-to-partner

Comment: It looks similar, but it isn't the same. I also read that issue to begin with and double checked that the gmail account wasn't a GSuite account. Also, the error message I'm getting is different as well.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I had to migrate my Nest account to a Google account to start this process, but after returning and following the documentation I get the same error message.

Comment: I've been experimenting with changing the consent screen, deleting and recreating projects, and so forth. It seems using the "Enable the API and get an OAuth 2.0 Client ID" button on the getting started page got me to the proper connection screen once or twice, but I am now back to getting the no partner connections found screen again. However, I have noticed that even though it shows a no partner connections found, I do get an email about the connection being established. The problem is, if I don't get a URI redirect callback with the Authorization Code, I can't go and get an access token.

Comment: So, according to https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/errors/pcm, this may be because my Google account has already been linked to a Device Access project. However, since I can't pull it up in the partner connection list, there doesn't seem to be a way for me to revoke that access. Sort of a weird catch here.

Comment: I'm having an issue like this - did you ever end up solving your problem? I've tried everything I can including order of operations when creating the GCP project, the Device Access project, etc and I still get "No Partner Connections Found". My Next account is migrated to google and everything seems to be fine there.

Comment: Can open a ticket on the public issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/) ? Also it would be great if you can add a video recording of the issue you are encountering .